# xpath escaping everything inside <>, how to fix that? Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

When **scraping** with Scrapy, while scraping text, in strings where they used `<>` instead of `«»`, everything gets lost.
e.g. `"<<Title>> continuation of title"` outputs `"<> continuation of title"`.
Same happens using both xpath and css selectors.

**How can I tell the program that these contents inside text shall not be treated as html and dropped?**

Here is my selector code (names of classes are dummy)

```
item = the_item.css('h3.class::text').get()
item = the_item.xpath('//p[@class="class"]/text()').get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my scrapy project is part of a Django project, I have imported strip_tags() from Django and just used that function on the scraped objects before saving.

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
```

than

```
...
item['title'] = strip_tags(item_title)
```

I hope this helps someone encountering my situation.

Comment: So, when you said “outputs "<> continuation of title"”, you meant in a web browser, the actual output was "<<Title>> continuation of title" as expected, right?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes. exactly!

Answer (score 2):

Fix the HTML first:

```py
good_html = bad_html.sub('<<', '&lt;&lt;').sub('>>', '&gt;&gt;')
```